# MVC.net: Call a function on every page load of the application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an mvc.net project with multiple pages & layouts.

I have a function I would like to call on every page when the page is loading.

Is there a place I can use the call for the function to apply for all pages? I don't want to add the call in each page or layout.

Is it possible? What about `global.asax`?

Comment: there is nothing such as page load in asp.net mvc,are you talking about index methods for each controller?

Comment: what does this function do?

Comment: The function checks existence of a cookie. Now I am calling it from the view of thelayout page.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways but if you want to use the global.asax then you can take advantage of the BeginRequest event handler. It's part of the System.Web.HttpApplication class.

[MSDN: BeginRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I would like to call this function every time a page is loaded and to do it once.
'Application_BeginRequest' is calling the function on every request.

Comment: Quick question - would you like to capture each action method call or every call to a "page"? So invalid page calls would be captured that don't resolve to an action method.

Comment: If it's just valid action method calls then you might want to look into Global Filters, it came out in MVC 3. This link might prove useful: http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit you every Controller from BaseController and in BaceController you can call your functoon